# validate asp.net xhtml strict via URI

Tags: asp.net, validation, xhtml, uri, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have an asp.net website which is using the xhtml strict dtd & making use of xhtmlConformance mode in web.config.
When validated by source I get zero errors but when by URI I get 2 errors

**there is no attribute "name"**

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
```

I don't know where that name attribute has come from. It doesn't exist in the outputted xhtml.

The second error is because it sees the viewstate as not being wrapped in a div, (even though it is).

Not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why a `name` attribute is being generated is because ASP.NET automatically creates a `name` attribute if you do not specify one.

According to a [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163736.aspx):

> A form must have a unique name. **One is
>   assigned automatically by ASP.NET if
>   you don't specify one.** You can set the
>   form's identifier by using either the
>   ID or Name property. If both are set,
>   the ID attribute takes precedence. It
>   is important to note, though, that any
>   programmatic use of the Name attribute
>   compromises the XHTML compliance of
>   the page. In XHTML, elements are
>   identified by ID and not by Name. So
>   generally speaking, you're better off
>   relying on the ID property.

However, there is a way to drop the `name` attribute: Use [XHTML Fixes](http://xhtmlfix.codeplex.com/). (See [this ASP.NET forum thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1557431/3872433.aspx) for more information.)

About your second `<div>` error: can you copy the source code from your browser (not the source you wrote) and paste it there? That will help us find the issue with that error.

EDIT: [This question about validating ASP.NET as XHTML 1.0 Strict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155532/xhtml-1-0-strict-or-transitional-compliance-in-asp-net-2-0-3-5) should be useful.